# Do i need a logo for submitting an app to the app store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I am submitting an app to the app store however I dont have a logo as it is taking longer than usual for my partner to get it up. We have however set a date for it to be submitted and i was wondering if any of you knew if it would be possible to submit an iphone app without a logo?

Thanks

Comment: When you say Logo do you mean App Icon?

Comment: Shame about your partner ;) but yes, you need an Icon

Comment: I doubt the binary will even validate without all the required icons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need an icon to submit the app for approval. Apple wants to see you icon before the app goes live, and you can not change it without submitting a new binary.